# openxml update 2 cells in same row throws an exception

Tags: c#, openxml

In my Template I like to update 2 cells in the same row. First cell is A53 and second cell is C53.

The exception is this "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

I call the method "UpdateCell" in the proccess I call the method "InsertCellInWorksheet" where the error happens.

The error happens in following line, but only after the second UpdateCell method is called and only when they are on the same line

```
if (row.Elements<Cell>().Where(c => c.CellReference.Value == cellReference).Count() > 0)
```

I have to mention that in the `FooterText5[0].CellText` array is an emailadress and has an @ in it.

This is where I start the whole thing

```
ExcelCreator.UpdateCell(ms, FooterText3[0].CellText, FooterText3[0].RowIndex, "A");
ExcelCreator.UpdateCell(ms, FooterText5[0].CellText, FooterText5[0].RowIndex, "C");
```

My code for the "UpdateCell" method:

```
public static void UpdateCell(Stream template, string cellText, uint rowIndex, string columnName, bool bold = false, int rowHeight = 0)
    {
        // Memorystream of the Template
        using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(template, true))
        {
            // get the first worksheet
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.
            Cell cell = InsertCellInWorksheet(columnName, rowIndex, worksheetPart);
// some other unrelated code
```

And the "InsertCellInWorksheet" method

```
    public static Cell InsertCellInWorksheet(string columnName, uint rowIndex, WorksheetPart worksheetPart)
        {
            Worksheet worksheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
            SheetData sheetData = worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
            string cellReference = columnName + rowIndex;


            Row row;
            if (sheetData.Elements<Row>().Where(r => r.RowIndex == rowIndex).Count() != 0)
            {
                row = sheetData.Elements<Row>().Where(r => r.RowIndex == rowIndex).First();
            }
            else
            {
                row = new Row() { RowIndex = rowIndex };
                sheetData.Append(row);
            }
if (row.Elements<Cell>().Where(c => c.CellReference.Value == cellReference).Count() > 0)
                {
                    return row.Elements<Cell>().Where(c => c.CellReference.Value == cellReference).First();
                }
                else
                {
                    // Cells must be in sequential order according to CellReference. Determine where to insert the new cell.
                    Cell refCell = null;
                    foreach (Cell cell in row.Elements<Cell>())
                    {
                        if (string.Compare(cell.CellReference.Value, cellReference, true) > 0)
                        {
                            refCell = cell;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    Cell newCell = new Cell() { CellReference = cellReference };
                    row.InsertBefore(newCell, refCell);

                    worksheet.Save();
                    return newCell;
                }
```

Where is my problem that the code has an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out.

I changed this line

```
if (row.Elements<Cell>().Where(c => c.CellReference.Value == cellReference).Count() > 0)
            {
                return row.Elements<Cell>().Where(c => c.CellReference.Value == cellReference).First();
            }
```

to this

```
if (row.Elements<Cell>().Where(c => c.CellReference != null && c.CellReference.Value == cellReference).Count() > 0)
            {
                return row.Elements<Cell>().Where(c => c.CellReference != null && c.CellReference.Value == cellReference).Single();
            }
```